# Pulling comment scores from Reddit, greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, jquery, reddit

I'm looking to write a greasemonkey script, and I need to pull the score from each comment so I can add my own stylizing to it after. Here's what I have now:

The reddit source looks as follows (this appears for each comments)

```
<p class="tagline">
    <span class="score unvoted">16 points</span>
```

And my javascript I'm attempting to write is so far, as follows

```
var i, tags = document.querySelectorAll('.tagline');
for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++) {

    var pullVotes = document.getElementsByClassName('.score'); //gets an Object HTMLCollection
    var collectionPull = Array.prototype.slice.call(pullVotes); //My attempt to convert the HTMLCollection to an array
    var userVote = collectionPull[0];

    tags[i].innerHTML += "<span> ("+userVote+")</span>";
}
```

I get "undefined". I also know there's reddit json I could use, but I couldn't find a way to pull the score from all comments, just from a static one that I set.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `I get "undefined"` — *what* is undefined?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the relevant parts of the source data

Comment: And why do you want to convert an HTML *Collection* to an array? Maybe this [documentation of the HTMLCollection type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is of help for you

Answer (score 0):

First, what went wrong:

```
var pullVotes = document.getElementsByClassName('.score'); //gets an Object HTMLCollection
```

Yes, it does return an HTMLCollection object, but your line looks for the class named ".score" not for the class "score", so this line returns an **empty** collection.

```
var collectionPull = Array.prototype.slice.call(pullVotes); //My attempt to convert the HTMLCollection to an array
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here, because HTMLCollection does have the `item(n)` method which returns... yes, the item at index `n` (as shown in the documentation of the [HTMLCollection class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection))

```
var userVote = collectionPull[0];
```

Ok, now even if the first line did work, this would always assign the first element of the collection to `userVote`, meaning the following line

```
tags[i].innerHTML += "<span> ("+userVote+")</span>";
```

would assign the same value to ***all*** scores on the page.

### Fixed

Sadly, I don't know what you intended "(userVotes)" to actually contain, so I don't think this will solve all your issues but that is all I can do with the information you gave:

```
var i, tags = document.querySelectorAll('.tagline');
for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++) {
    // get all elements with class 'score' that are inside the tagline
    var userVote = tags[i].getElementsByClassName('score').item(0);

    // do something with this element
    userVote.style="background-color: red";
}
```

### jQuery

Since reddit has jQuery on their page, you can also simply do (for example)

```
var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
$('.tagline .score').css('background-color', 'red');
```